# How to enable CORS for the Apache NiFi API?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Apache NiFi to perform some ETL tasks and I want to manage the ETL pipeline with Apache Airflow. Since there is no integration between NiFi and Airflow, I have decided to create a Python script that will request a token and trigger my first processor. Locally, it works very well, but when I try to use it from Airflow, it displays a `Connection refused` error. I assumed it was a CORS issue. Then, I tried to `fetch('https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/access')` from my browser console, and it displayed `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/access. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.` So, I looked at the NiFi documentation, but I couldn't find anything. Then, I found this (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-9241) where it says that they removed and disabled the CORS configuration in NiFi version 1.15.

Apache NiFi version: 1.20.0
Apache Airflow version: 2.5.3

My Python script that works locally:

```py
import requests
import json
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    nifi_endpoint = "https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/"
    # Authentication
    access_endpoint = "access/token"
    access_headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Accept': "*/*"
    }
    access_payload = {
        'username': "censored",
        'password': "censored"
    }
    token = requests.post(
        url=nifi_endpoint+access_endpoint,
        headers=access_headers,
        data=access_payload,
        verify=False
    ).content.decode("ascii")
    # Get processor infos
    processor_endpoint = "processors/"
    get_processor_headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)
    }
    infos = json.loads(requests.get(
        url=nifi_endpoint+processor_endpoint+"45ea3d63-0187-1000-504f-94ef71fe776c",
        headers=get_processor_headers,
        verify=False
    ).content)
    # Starting pipeline
    put_processor_headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)
    }
    put_processor_payload = {
        'revision': infos["revision"],
        'state': "RUNNING",
        'disconnectedNodeAcknowledge': True
    }
    response = requests.put(
        url=nifi_endpoint+processor_endpoint+"45ea3d63-0187-1000-504f-94ef71fe776c"+"/run-status",
        headers=put_processor_headers,
        data=json.dumps(put_processor_payload).encode("utf8"),
        verify=False
    )
    put_processor_payload = {
        'revision': infos["revision"],
        'state': "STOPPED",
        'disconnectedNodeAcknowledge': True
    }
    response = requests.put(
        url=nifi_endpoint+processor_endpoint+"45ea3d63-0187-1000-504f-94ef71fe776c"+"/run-status",
        headers=put_processor_headers,
        data=json.dumps(put_processor_payload).encode("utf8"),
        verify=False
    )
```